# Include ActivityScope modules only once in Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using Dagger2 as my dependency injector in android. The problem I am facing is the number of modules in `ActivityScope`.
So like any other project I have two type of modules.

1. `Singleton`s (Which are included only once and in my `ApplicationComponent`
2. `ActivityScope`s (Which are included on each `ActivityComponent`)

As the project is expanded the number of my `ActivityScope` Modules are increasing and therefore it is getting more and more time each time a new module is added. Plus the number of modules included on every `ActivityComponent` is making the code very unreadable. I'm looking for a way to include the modules which are included in all activities only once (Still in `ActivityScope`) so each `ActivityComponent` requires only it's explicit modules to be mentioned.

Here is part of my code which might be helpful:

**ApplicationComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ContextModule.class,
        AppLangModule.class,
        ...
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent  extends AndroidInjector<MainApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainApplication> {
        abstract Builder contextModule(ContextModule contextModule);
        abstract Builder appLangModule(AppLangModule appLangModule);
        ...
    }
}
```

**ApplicationModule.java**

```
@Module
abstract class ApplicationModule {
    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules ={
            CategoryRepositoryModule.class,
            DictionaryRepositoryModule.class,
            TranslationRepositoryModule.class,
            StatsRepository.StatsRepositoryModule.class,
            WordCardRepositoryModule.class,
            WordCardUserDataRepository.CouchBaseCardRepositoryModule.class,
            StatsManager.StatsManagerModule.class,
            WordCardIdProviderFactoryModule.class,
            CustomSubCategoryRepository.CustomSubCategoryRepositoryModule.class,
            ConfigurationRepository.ConfigurationRepositoryModule.class})
    abstract Activity1 provideActivity1();

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules ={
            CategoryRepositoryModule.class,
            DictionaryRepositoryModule.class,
            TranslationRepositoryModule.class,
            StatsRepository.StatsRepositoryModule.class,
            WordCardRepositoryModule.class,
            WordCardUserDataRepository.CouchBaseCardRepositoryModule.class,
            StatsManager.StatsManagerModule.class,
            WordCardIdProviderFactoryModule.class,
            CustomSubCategoryRepository.CustomSubCategoryRepositoryModule.class,
            ConfigurationRepository.ConfigurationRepositoryModule.class})
    abstract Activity2 provideActivity2();
    ...
}
```

Of course, Not all of my activities require this many modules (most of the modules are required by other modules).

Comment: Are you using Constructor Injection? This looks an awful lot like you call `new MyClass()` for every one of your classes in your modules.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak, Yes and no :D, my components are not using Constructor injections. But the modules are created on their Provide methods (If that's what you mean) and usually take dependencies in constructor

Comment: Provide methods are _not_ constructor injection. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45422229/1837367

Comment: @DavidMedenjak thanx a lot, That was actually very helpful. But there is an slight problem here, which most of these modules are providing for interfaces. is there anyway to set a default implementation for @Inject?

Comment: Have a look at `@Binds` to bind interfaces to implementations. Your module would then be just an abstract class or also an interface

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Thanx a lot, I suggest you post this information as the answer, so I pick it as the right answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151834/discussion-between-hossein-shahdoost-and-david-medenjak).

Answer (score 2):

[`Module.includes`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Module.html#includes--) allows you to compose modules into a single module class:

```
@Module(
    includes = {
        CategoryRepositoryModule.class,
        DictionaryRepositoryModule.class,
        TranslationRepositoryModule.class,
        StatsRepository.StatsRepositoryModule.class,
        WordCardRepositoryModule.class,
        WordCardUserDataRepository.CouchBaseCardRepositoryModule.class,
        StatsManager.StatsManagerModule.class,
        WordCardIdProviderFactoryModule.class,
        CustomSubCategoryRepository.CustomSubCategoryRepositoryModule.class,
        ConfigurationRepository.ConfigurationRepositoryModule.class
    }
)
final class SharedActivityModule {}
```

Then,

```
@Module
abstract class ApplicationModule {
    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {
        SharedActivityModule.class, 
        /* Activity1 specific modules */,
    })
    abstract Activity1 provideActivity1();

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {
        SharedActivityModule.class, 
        /* Activity2 specific modules */,
    })
    abstract Activity2 provideActivity2();
}
```