# pass parameter to provider method when injecting the instance

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am new in Dagger 2. I created a module which has a provider method that takes one String parameter:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

  @Provides
  Student provideStudent(String name) {
    return new Student(name); 
  }
}
```

How should I pass the parameter `name` when injecting student? `@Inject Student student`? But where/How can I pass the `name` in?

Comment: *How should I pass the parameter in consumer (Activity/Fragment) where I would like to inject student?* Could you elaborate a little bit more ?

Comment: where does name come from ?

Comment: From anywhere I would like to create a student. I mean my project can create a student instance whenever needed, and hardcode the name.

Comment: but in the end the activity/fragment will get in a bundle ?

Comment: My question is how to inject a student instance with a name can be hardcoded during injecting.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you should have a look at _Constructor Injection_, because with Dagger you should not be calling `new` yourself anymore. That whole provides method could be replaced with a single `@Inject`, e.g. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45422229/1837367

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dagger 2: Injecting user inputted parameter into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516736/dagger-2-injecting-user-inputted-parameter-into-object)

Answer (score 4):

You want to supply an object (`String name`) as a parameter to your component so that it can be used by other parts. You basically have 2 options to do so.

### Module Constructor Parameters

Using module arguments is the "classic" approach that you would use before they introduced the `Component.Builder`.

All you do is add what you need to your module constructor, and provide it from the module.

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

  private String name;

  MyModule(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  // -----------------------------------------------
  // you could obviously just use the field directly
  @Provides
  Student provideStudent() {
    return new Student(name); 
  }


  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  // alternatively you'd add a Qualifier and add the argument to the graph
  @Provides
  @Named("name")
  String provideName() {
    return name; 
  }

  // then you can use it...
  @Provides
  Student provideStudent(@Named("name") String name) {
    return new Student(name); 
  }

}
```

The first option that directly uses the name means that it's only available within *that* module. If you want to make use of constructor injection or use the qualified String you have to add it to the graph as shown second.

With either approach you'd have to manually add the module to the component, since the module does no longer use a default constructor. This is where you'd also supply your argument now.

```
DaggerMyComponent.builder()
        .myModule(new MyModule("some name"))
        .build();
```

### Component Builder

The same concept but a different approach would be to use the component builder to achieve the same thing—bind something to the graph.

```
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
interface MyComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance Builder name(@Named("name") String name);

        MyComponent build();
    }
}

@Module
class MyModule {

    @Provides
    Student provideStudent(@Named("name") String name) {
        return new Student(name);
    }

}
```

Here you also just add an object to the graph that can be used. Here, too, you'd have to add it to the component builder

```
DaggerMyComponent.builder()
        .name("some name")
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how to inject a student instance with a name can be
>   hardcoded.

`name` is a dependency of `Student`, and this dependency as to be resolved. To do so you need an annotated `@Provid`e method that returns that `String`. Since the type is usually inferred by the return type, in case of `String` you will have to use also the annotation `@Named`

```
@Provides
@Named("Name")
public String provideName() {
    return "My name";
}
```

and change your method like

```
@Provides
Student provideStudent(@Named("Name") String name) {
   return new Student(name); 
}
```

this way dagger2 knows ho to resolve that `String` to build `Student`

Comment: THanks, but it is not a enough answer for my question, because I am asking how to pass the name string during @Inject phase, that's during consuming phase not providing phase. You only answered how to do it in provider (providing phase)

Comment: to `MyModule` you mean ?

Comment: e.g. in My Activity, I need a instance of student, how to inject such instance? My question has mentioned `@Inject Student student` but how can I define `name` there? I want to `name` to be defined during consuming phase not providing phase. In general, my Activity/Fragment want to inject a student instance with name be anything Activity/Fragment prefer to use.

Comment: every time you start your activity/fragment, you have a different student name, and you want dagger2 to build Student for you? Sorry but I am having trouble understanding what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: Without dagger 2, in Activity or any class which needs student instance, I do `Student student = new Student("Whatever name I want")` , with dagger 2, I do `@Inject Student student`, but how to pass "Whatever name I want" here? That's my question. I don't want to define name in module because I want those class which needs student define the name.

Comment: I think I got it now. As far as I know, it is not possible to achieve what you want  without the Module having knowledge of Name. The easiest, as you can image, is to provide a setter to `Student`. Up to a certain extent and with a slightly more complex setup,  a smaller scope might allow you to get close to it (I can provide a gist with some code if you want)

Comment: thanks, I'll wait for a day to see if other people have good solutions, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: ping me if you want see the "slightly more complex setup" solution

Comment: Sure, I would like to see :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of injecting the `Student` directly, you could create a `Student` factory and inject it instead:

```java
public class Student {
    public Student(String name, Knowledge knowledge) {}

    public static class Factory {
        private Knowledge knowledge;

        @Inject
        public Factory(Knowledge knowledge) {
            this.knowledge = knownledge;
        }

        public Student create(String name) {
            return new Student(name, knowledge);
        }
    }
}
```

Or the same code in Kotlin:

```
class Student(name: String, knowledge: Knowledge) {
    class Factory @Inject constructor(private val knowledge: Knowledge) {
        fun create(name: String) = Student(name, knowledge)
    }
}
```

This allows passing the `name` parameter on `Student` instantiation, like this:

```java
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    public Student.Factory studentFactory;
    private Student student;

    public void setupStudent() {
        this.student = studentFactory.create("Student's name");
    }
}
```